# Deleting Duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, alter-table

Query was this:

```
CREATE TABLE `query` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`searchquery` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`datetime` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

first I want to drop the table with:

```
ALTER TABLE `querynew` DROP `id`
```

and then delete the double entries.. 
I tried it with:

```
INSERT INTO `querynew` SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `query`
```

but with no success.. :(

and with `ALTER TABLE query ADD UNIQUE ( searchquery )` - is it possible to save the queries only one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using an index with the MySQL-specific [`IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) keyword. This kills two birds with one stone: it deletes duplicate rows, and adds a unique index so that you will not get any more of them. It is usually faster than the other methods as well:

```
alter ignore table query add unique index(searchquery, datetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use MySQL's multi-table delete syntax:

```
DELETE q2 FROM query q1 JOIN query q2 USING (searchquery, datetime)
WHERE q1.id < q2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it without first removing the column:

```
DELETE FROM `query`
 WHERE `id` IN (
        SELECT `id`
          FROM `query` q
         WHERE EXISTS ( -- Any matching rows with a lower id?
                SELECT *
                  FROM `query`
                 WHERE `searchquery` = q.`searchquery`
                   AND `datetime` = q.`datetime`
                   AND `id` < q.`id`
               )
       );
```

You could also go via a temp table:

```
SELECT MIN(`id`), `searchquery`, `datetime`
  INTO `temp_query`
 GROUP BY `searchquery`, `datetime`;

DELETE FROM `query`;

INSERT INTO `query` SELECT * FROM `temp_query`;
```

Comment: no success, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'q WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `query` WHERE `sea' at line 1

Comment: the second give's this error: #1327 - Undeclared variable: temp_query  :( but I created the same table as temp_query..

Comment: D'oh! That one always gets me. Fixed (I hope).

Comment: The second one uses SQL Server syntax. I don't know the exact equivalent in MySQL, but you could separately create the temp table, and then just insert into it. In any case, @Bill's answer is way better than mine, so all this is moot.